# Javascript 'in' function throwing an error in console

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a javascript function as follows:

```
        if (',' in mpttexclusion){
            $scope.exclusion = $scope.mpttexclusion.split(',');
        } else {
            $scope.exclusion = $scope.mpttexclusion;
        }
```

But when i check the console, i am getting this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for ',' in 175
    at new ModalInstanceCtrl (http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/js/app.js:180:15)
    at invoke (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.js:3704:17)
    at Object.instantiate (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.js:3715:23)
    at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.js:6766:28
    at http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.10.0.min.js:8:22381
    at wrappedCallback (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.js:10943:81)
    at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.js:11029:26
    at Scope.$eval (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.js:11949:28)
    at Scope.$digest (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.js:11775:31)
    at Scope.$apply (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.js:12055:24) angular.js:9413
(anonymous function) angular.js:9413
(anonymous function) angular.js:6832
wrappedCallback angular.js:10946
(anonymous function) angular.js:11029
Scope.$eval angular.js:11949
Scope.$digest angular.js:11775
Scope.$apply angular.js:12055
(anonymous function) angular.js:17833
(anonymous function) angular.js:2612
forEach angular.js:309
eventHandler angular.js:2611
```

I checked a few questions already but i am not sure if i am able to totally understand the error here.

Comment: Why not simple `if(mpttexclusion.indexOf(',') > -1)`?

Comment: if (',' in mpttexclusion) --> this is strange. Do you mean "if ($scope.mpttexclusion)?"

Comment: `in` finds properties in objects, not substrings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use indexOf instead:

```
if($scope.mpttexclusion.indexOf(',') >= 0)
  $scope.exclusion = $scope.mpttexclusion.split(',');
else
  $scope.exclusion = $scope.mpttexclusion;
```

Comment: hi i am getting an "Object 175 has no method indexOf()"

Comment: what is the value of $scope.mpttexclusion??

Comment: Its just 175 for now but later in the stage, it may get values like 123,456,345..

Comment: Is there another way to check for values in a string and split them?

Comment: If it's a string, indexOf will work. Make sure it is not a falsy value, like undefined or null, and make sure its type is not 'number'.

Comment: Hi, i realized it is a value coming in from a json. Has that got anything to do with it>

Comment: how will integers have commas in it??

Answer (score 1):

You should do like,

```
if (mpttexclusion.indexOf(',') > -1){
```

instead of

```
if (',' in mpttexclusion){
```

since `in` basically used in iteration like,

```
var x = [10,2,3,1];

for(val in x){
 console.log(val);
}
```

Comment: you should write `$scope.mpttexclusion.indexOf(',')`

Answer (score 0):

As Frédéric pointed out in the comments of the initial question:

```
for (var x in object) {
  ...some code...
}
```

is rather used for Objects than for Strings.

Or as [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) describes it:

> Iterates over the enumerable properties of an object, in arbitrary
>   order. For each distinct property, statements can be executed.

As the others already pointed out the correct answer I just thought I link to a resource that might help you to understand the problem with the approach to being with.

Hope this helps